# How to execute JavaScript using Karate's driver

Tags: karate

I want to achieve something like:
WebElement ele = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
.executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot",element);
using Karate's driver object.
please let me know how to achieve(.executeScript()) the same using Karate's driver object

Answer (score 1):

You can use `driver.eval()` to execute any JS in the browser:

```
* assert driver.eval('1 + 2') == 3
* match driver.eval('location.href') == webUrlBase + '/page-01'
```